# How to read json response from retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

How to read this response from retrofit and store to java class and access somewhere ??

```
{
    "user": {
        "__v": 0,
        "updated_at": "2017-11-08T12:07:46.729Z",
        "created_at": "2017-11-08T12:07:46.729Z",
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QzIiwidXNlcmlkIjozLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFydWwzQHRlc3QuY29tIiwiYWNjZXNzX2xldmVsIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJfaWQiOiI1YTAyZjM5Mjk5OGM4OTI3MjQxYTQ3N2YiLCJncm91cHMiOlt7ImlkIjoxLCJuYW1lIjoiZGlhbGVyIiwiX2lkIjoiNThiM2JmODI5ZTg2MDFjMDVlNzIxNjI3In1dfQ.VKEt1JoXoL_xfRDrrFK-jVj8zC23j4sqZTT2S3HGMbc",
        "username": "test3",
        "userid": 3,
        "email": "arul3@test.com",
        "access_level": "Admin",
        "_id": "5a02f392998c8927241a477f",
        "groups": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "dialer",
            "_id": "58b3bf829e8601c05e721627"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Create model call of response  after that use Gson or Jackson which will parse your response to model class.

Comment: Follow that Questin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583379/json-response-using-retrofit-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create classes from pojo like that then parse to retrofit [Convert json response to classes](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

```
    public class MyPojo{
    private User user;

    public User getUser ()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser (User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

User Class:

```
    public class User{
    private String username;

    private String updated_at;

    private String _id;

    private String access_level;

    private String email;

    private String token;

    private String userid;

    private String __v;

    private String created_at;

    private Groups[] groups;

    public String getUsername ()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername (String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at ()
    {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at (String updated_at)
    {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public String get_id ()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id (String _id)
    {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getAccess_level ()
    {
        return access_level;
    }

    public void setAccess_level (String access_level)
    {
        this.access_level = access_level;
    }

    public String getEmail ()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getToken ()
    {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken (String token)
    {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getUserid ()
    {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid (String userid)
    {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String get__v ()
    {
        return __v;
    }

    public void set__v (String __v)
    {
        this.__v = __v;
    }

    public String getCreated_at ()
    {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at (String created_at)
    {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public Groups[] getGroups ()
    {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups (Groups[] groups)
    {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

}
```

Groups Class:

public class Groups{
      private String id;

```
private String _id;

private String name;

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String get_id ()
{
    return _id;
}

public void set_id (String _id)
{
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Now follow that put your classes and get desire response [Retrofit Json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583379/json-response-using-retrofit-on-android)